# How to remove all existing photo access permission for an app on iOS?

Tags: ios, permission

Suppose there are thousands of photos on iPhone and an app is permitted to access several of them. To remove all or some of these permissions, you need to browse all photos and find those photos and click them. It there an easier way to do this?

Comment: My understanding is that access to Photos meant access to all photos - it does for my apps. So what app are you using that only has access to specific photos?  Or is this just a "suppose" question without any real issue behind it?

Comment: @Gilby iOS and iPadOS can let you choose which photos an app can access, that's a feature for privacy protection. Apps cannot access other photos.